# Reason for making esp as reference for variables on 32bit OS while rbp on 64bit OS on intel machines?

Tags: x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, inline-assembly, stack-pointer

Below program is giving different output on 32bit and 64bit machine. When i checked its assembly code generated by compiler, i found that reference of variable on 32bit machine was esp while on 64bit OS it was rbp.

In my opinion ebp has to be the reference for variable since it remain constant in one function.

Is there any specific reason for not using ebp as reference for variables?

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main()
{
    int i=5;
    while(i)
    {
        printf("Hello world..\t");
        asm("push %rax"); // for 64bit OS
        //asm("push %eax"); // for 32bit OS
        printf("Have a nice day..\n");
        i--;
        asm("pop %rax"); // for 64bit OS
        //asm("pop %eax"); // for 32bit OS
    }
}
```

on 64bit OS
printed 6 times both of those lines

on 32bit OS
indefinite times(until it luckily gets 0) printing of both lines since eax was as reference to variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can rely on how the compiler will reference or use a variable.  As well as different results for different architectures, you will probably also get different results with different optimisation settings.

If you need to know where a variable is then the extended asm syntax is perhaps a better starting point: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am highly intended to know what make wheels roll; presently i am trying to develop AHCI driver for my own 32bit x86 OS. And to achieve that i need to do many practicals and simulations on Linux. This was one of those intermediary practicals.

Comment: "different results with different optimisation settings" - Or new releases of the compiler, or even minor, seemingly unrelated changes in the surrounding code.  Attempting to "crack the code" about how and where the compiler stores data is a *supremely* bad idea.  In fact, if you post a Q describing the specific task you are attempting to accomplish with asm(), the first thing people are going to explain to you is why using inline asm is such a bad idea and how builtins are better. Before you spend too much time walking down that path, take a minute to reconsider your actual requirements here.